# Output Spanish Character

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa

I need to print Ñ to screen.  I'm using this code and it works fine for everything but the capital Ñ.  It displays this: √ë.

```
CGContextShowText(textContext, [text UTF8String], strlen([text UTF8String]));
```

And, all these encodings give the same thing:

```
const char *cn = "Ñ";
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String: cn]);
NSLog(@"%C", 0x00d1);
NSLog(@"%@", @"Ñ");


2012-06-20 16:27:09.388 app[406:707] √ë
2012-06-20 16:27:09.392 app[406:707] √ë
2012-06-20 16:27:09.394 app[406:707] √ë
```

So, how do I display Ñ and not √ë, using NSLog or CGContextShowText?

Answer (score 1):

The following works properly on my Mac:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"Ñ"]);
```

Make sure the text encoding has been set correctly in Xcode:

[image: Xcode Encoding]

Comment: That does work.  Not sure that solves the problem though.  I think that CGContextShowText is a legacy function that doesn't accept the full range.  If I was using Core Text, this may not be a problem.